# Extract Discord user ID from a discord message

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am working on a python bot, and one thing I need is for the bot to see if someone @'d another person (i.e. I type something like "!callout @randomuser") in a discord channel. If it detects this, I want to get the user ID of the @'d user (in this case, the user ID of @randomuser)

I know this is probably a dumb question, but was unable to find an answer elsewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide evidence of your efforts, do you have sample code you have been working on?

Comment: Without any idea of the approach you are taking this might be of some use, https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to use the [converters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) that come with the `discord.ext.commands` extension.  That can give you a `User` object, which has a `User.id` attribute:

```
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord import User

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def getid(ctx, user: User):
    await bot.say("Their ID is {}".format(user.id))

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def callout(ctx, user: User):
    await bot.say("{}, someone is talking about you".format(user.mention))

bot.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using [mentions](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Message.mentions). This generates a list of users, for all users that were mentioned (@user) in a message. The advantage of this is that it easily handles multiple mentions. This works in the rewrite and async version of discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def test(ctx):
    users = ctx.message.mentions
    await ctx.send(users[0].id)
```